# Plot each column as a line and group by the first row of each column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib, plot

So I have a dataframe with 8-year energy values and types of the object on the first row. I need to plot all 3000 sources grouped by their types. 3000 Lines, X-axis is the 8 years, Y-axis is the energy.

[It's yearly energy and the type of source](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mzsjo.png)

Sorry if anything is missing, it's my first question.

I've tried to just delete the types and plot without grouping by:

```
blazar_eneryg_with_type.plot(x ='Year', kind = 'line')
```

#### Here's the result, that I need but only in 3 groups

[image: Here's the result, that I need but only in 3 groups]

Comment: Do you want a sum of the energy for each group ?

Comment: No, I need a plot just like on the second picture, but only in 3 colors, for 3 types

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok having seen your raw data you must have done some processing before hand. Looks like you are calling `df.plot()`. This is what I would do:

```
# read in your csv
df = pd.read_csv('your_csv')

# drop redundant column
df.drop(columns=['Unnamed: 0'], inplace=True)

#transpose and drop type column and create second df
df1 = df.T.drop(['type1'])

# create color map
colors = {'bcu': 'red', 'bll': 'blue', 'fsrq': 'green'}

# plot colors using mapping from the type column
df1.plot(color=df['type1'].apply(lambda x: colors[x]))
plt.show()
```

The graph is an absolute mess and I am not sure why you would want to plot that much data on a single chart but there you go.

EDIT : To change the legend

```
ax = df1.plot(color=df['type1'].apply(lambda x: colors[x]))
ax.legend(['bcu', 'bll', 'fsrq'])
plt.show()
```

Comment: https://filebin.net/a41q61gejw7wt57d/blazar_with_type.csv?t=9vwj3sa8
Sorry here's the data, I've tried your code, it's saying x and y must be the same size.

Comment: Thank you very much, that's what I've needed, just it showing every single line's info, I need just to show the color and corresponding type in the infobox, is it possible?